# I'm trying to use the turtle methods, etc. listed on the official python page but I keep getting errors

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm using turtle to create a video game.

I'm making this program for a virtual class, and I don't know the exact limitations of the (online) IDLE provided. I'm not currently able to test my code in any other environment. I don't want to use pygame or anything because I don't know if I can and also I don't want to rewrite a bunch of my code.

The problems I'm having are mostly with the TurtleScreen/Screen. I can't call .Screen() or .TurtleScreen(), .bgcolor(), .turtlesize(), and probably a lot more I haven't checked yet. Here's an example:

```
bg = turtle.Screen()
turt = turtle.Turtle()

bg.bgcolor("black")
```

I just receive a

> ParseError: bad input

when I run it. Any input is much appreciated!

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, not just a couple of lines out of context. It's difficult to explain why code we can't see isn't working. Please [edit] your post to include that [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

A parse error usually comes from python being unable to parse your code rather than an issue with Turtle.

The code snippet you posted above works fine so the problem is likely with some other lines of code that precede it. Double check your syntax on lines before the error occurs and make sure there aren't any missing parenthesis, brackets, quotes, etc that would impact later lines.